# 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' is not installed in project on Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm following the tutorial listed here:

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html

However, instead of including the DB context in the WebApplication project, I'd like the DB Context, Entities, etc to live inside another .NET Core Class Library.

I got around some early compatibility issues by updating the libraries project.json file to include the 'netcoreapp1.0' framework.

**project.json**

BEFORE:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.6": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
    }
}
```

AFTER:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "portable-net451+win8" ],
      "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
      },

      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0-*"
        },
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-*"
      },
      "tools": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    },
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The tutorial goes on to say that in order to 'reverse engineer your model' the following command must be run inside the package manager console:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

I get the following error message:

```
Cannot execute this command because 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' is not installed in project 'src\DB'. Add 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' to the 'tools' section in project.json. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221 for more details.
```

Where DB is the name of the class library.

You can clearly see Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools in the tools section. So I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Your project json seems invalid. There is no tools section in the schema within the framework. Only on the top level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tools section within "framework" section defined in the [project.json schema](http://json.schemastore.org/project).

This one should work correctly

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-*"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "portable-net451+win8" ],
      "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0-*"
        }
      }
    },
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So I the next error message I got was telling me to set the class library as the 'start up' project. After doing that, the Scaffold-DbContext command fails because the "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"

Comment: So I went with the next logical steps and just added a main method. I got the following message: This preview of Entity Framework tools does not support commands on class library projects in ASP.NET Core and .NET Core applications. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221 for details and workarounds.

Comment: Maybe its because it sees your netstandard1.6 section still there